# What's a good introduction to computational discrete math?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, soft-question, computational-mathematics

I'm not looking for an intro to proofs book, I'm looking for a book that does for discrete math what e.g. Stewart's calculus books do for continuous math: a beginner-friendly, comprehensive introduction to basic computational techniques, with lots of exercises. Specifically, I want it to cover things like evaluating summations, solving recurrences, asymptotics, and working with the functions that come up a lot in discrete math (factorials, falling powers, binomial coefficients, etc). Also, I'm not looking for Knuth's Concrete Mathematics.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have an issue with Knuth, Graham, and Patashnik's _Concrete Mathematics_? Or are you already aware of it and looking for _more_ references? Because it is absolutely my first choice of recommendation

Comment: I have issues with it. For example, according to the authors one goal of the book is to make students as comfortable with sums as they are with integrals. The reason students are so comfortable with integrals is bc theyve read books like Stewart's which spend 3-4 chs systematically going through all the different kinds of integrals you'll generally see, and giving specific techniques for evaluating each kind. It also has hundreds of exercises on evaluating straightforward integrals. Knuth has 1 disorganized chapter on sums with ~3 straightforward "evaluate the sum" exercises.